# Convert find words in a string

Tags: python

I have an output of a command like that as an example :

```
Time = XX ,info =XX , mesg=XXXX

{
 "description":"add by the customer"
 "group": " group black "
 "id" :1,
 "name": "group_1"
 "Num": "No-648747464598"
}

{
 "description":"add by the customer"
 "group": "group black "
 "id" :2,
 "name": "group_2"
 "Num": "No-7464674846"
}

{
 "description":"add by the customer"
 "group": " group black "
 "id" :3,
 "name": "group_3"
 "Num": "No-9950509505"
}
```

How can I use the string function and split so if I give a name will get the Num?
Example :

```
Fonction X (group_3):
 return No-9950509505
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could enumerate the lines and then fetch the data you need like following:

```
def func(group_name):
    c = -1
    group = 'group_3'
    for idx, i in enumerate(x.splitlines()):
        if c != -1:
            return i.split(':')[1].replace('"', '')
        if group_name in i:
            c= idx
```

Comment: how i can  create a list and add all the numbers to a list: Example Fonction X (group_3):
 return [No-9950509505,No-6454638,No-747484]